# Static Method With Class Name Also?

Tags: c#, methods

I'm looking at a piece of code I don't fully understand.  This is how it looks:

```
public static ClassName MethodName(int parameter){
    //Method does its thing
}
```

Is there a name for this type of code pattern?  Also, what is it being used for?

Comment: whoever wrote that method had a weird sense of humor

Comment: Not "Class Name Also". It returns something of type ClassName. Could be its own class or another. It's not `static void ClassName MethodName()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply a static method which returns an object of type `ClassName`.  Do you mean that it is declared inside of the `ClassName` class?  This is fine, it just means that the class in question has a static method which returns an instance of itself.  This is commonly used in the Factory Pattern, for example.  Rather than manually instantiate an instance of the class, a static method is called which returns an instance.

Comment: Did you copy that first line word-for-word from my post? =P

Comment: @Ed S.: Heh, I didn't even notice that.  We were within a minute of each other, though :)  I rarely click on that "load new answers" link that appears.  I find it distracting and _have_ been tempted to copy.  It does oneself a disservice in the pursuit of giving good answers :)

Comment: Wow, of course that's the answer.  I don't know why I wasn't able to figure such a simple thing out.  I'm used to seeing public int doStuff(), so variable types are usually the return types, not whole classes.   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a static method that returns an object of type "ClassName".  Looks like it could be a factory method(?)

> Also, what is it being used for?

Can't really answer that seeing as there is no definition in your example.  It's just a method signature with generic names.

Answer (score 0):

In you example the method returns an instance of class `ClassName`.

This is really equivalent to any other method, equivalent to `public static String MethodName()`. It's fairly common to create a static method on a class, which returns an instance of the same class, i.e. a factory method.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a class method. You don't have to instantiate anything to call it. It can only access other static methods and fields, because without an instance you can't call any non-static(non-class) variables.